# Use awk command line to combine columns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I  want to use awk to combine columns starting from 4th column till the end of columns.

Input:

```
1   682333  191.858 191517119   C   A   C   A   A   A   C   A   A   A   A   A
2   1862626 71.9275 56032940    A   C   C   C   A   A   A   C   A   C   A   A
3   11957134    155.78  150230950   B   B   B   B   A   B   A   B   A   B   A   B
4   2516482 51.2692 31496569    B   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
5   9378200 51.2798 31572927    A   A   B   B   B   A   A   A   A   A   B   A
6   2071534 52.1573 32824318    A   B   A   B   A   B   A   B   B   B   A   B
7   2074633 33.068  19035920    A   A   B   A   A   A   B   A   B   A   B   A
8   7856856 121.811 117540910   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   B   A   B   A
9   3741206 2.18574 2169864 A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
10  4411364 12.5959 24191374    C   C   A   C   A   C   C   C   A   C   A   C
```

Output:

```
1   682333  191.858 191517119   CA      CA      AA      CA      AA      AA
2   1862626 71.9275 56032940    AC      CC      AA      AC      AC      AA
3   11957134    155.78  150230950   BB      BB      AB      AB      AB      AB
4   2516482 51.2692 31496569    BA      AA      AA      AA      AA      AA
5   9378200 51.2798 31572927    AA      BB      BA      AA      AA      BA
6   2071534 52.1573 32824318    AB      AB      AB      AB      BB      AB
7   2074633 33.068  19035920    AA      BA      AA      BA      BA      BA
8   7856856 121.811 117540910   AA      AA      AA      AA      BA      BA
9   3741206 2.18574 2169864 AA      AA      AA      AA      AA      AA
10  4411364 12.5959 24191374    CC      AC      AC      CC      AC      AC
```

By the way, if there is any good website for an awk command tutorial, please recommend it here.

Comment: For a tutorial, you could start with [\[ this \]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

Comment: And after you've read the tutorial, come back to the question and post what you've done to solve the problem

Comment: Buy the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @sjsam I always recommend people buy the book instead of suggesting they read it for free online as the guy who wrote it deserves to make a few bucks off that plus all the work he's put into providing and maintaining gawk for us and shouldn't be penalized for graciously also providing it online for reference.

Comment: @EdMorton : You've just made a good point..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my book, 'one-liner' is a term of abuse unless the code fits on a single line under about 80 characters.  I think `awk` code is more easily understood when formatted using multiple lines for multiple statements.  Hence, I came up with this marginally different version of the code.  The case where there's an odd number of fields on the line doesn't need special treatment.  Accessing `$(NF+1)` will give an empty string (or zero number).

```
awk '{  printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", $1, $2, $3, $4)
        for (i = 5; i <= NF; i += 2)
            printf("\t%s%s", $i, $(i+1))
        print ""
     }' data
```

Judging from the data layout in the question, tab separators were used in the original data, but the presentation is with tabstops set at 4 spaces.  Hence the code uses tabs as the separator character.  I added an extra line to the sample data containing:

```
11  1111111 22.2222 33333333    D   D   W   W   X   X   Y   Y   Z   Z   =
```

The output I got from that plus the data in the question looked like this after formatting with tabstops set to 4:

```
1   682333  191.858 191517119   CA  CA  AA  CA  AA  AA
2   1862626 71.9275 56032940    AC  CC  AA  AC  AC  AA
3   11957134    155.78  150230950   BB  BB  AB  AB  AB  AB
4   2516482 51.2692 31496569    BA  AA  AA  AA  AA  AA
5   9378200 51.2798 31572927    AA  BB  BA  AA  AA  BA
6   2071534 52.1573 32824318    AB  AB  AB  AB  BB  AB
7   2074633 33.068  19035920    AA  BA  AA  BA  BA  BA
8   7856856 121.811 117540910   AA  AA  AA  AA  BA  BA
9   3741206 2.18574 2169864 AA  AA  AA  AA  AA  AA
10  4411364 12.5959 24191374    CC  AC  AC  CC  AC  AC
11  1111111 22.2222 33333333    DD  WW  XX  YY  ZZ  =
```

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to @sps answer but without the if and using tabs

```
awk '{ printf $1; for (i=2; i<=4; i++) {printf "\t%s",$i}; for (i=5; i<=NF; i+=2) {  printf "\t%s%s",$i,$(i+1);} printf "\n"; }' filename
```

Comment: Try that when the input file contains a line that starts with, say, `%s`. Always use `printf "%s", $1` instead of `printf $1`. Also, always use `print ""` instead of `printf "\n"` so you terminate lines with the current `ORS` instead of hard-coding a value.

Comment: At that level of pickiness also OFS should be used instead of "\t"

Comment: Correct, sorry I missed that one. The whole thing should really be written as (untested) `awk -v OFS='\t' '{ for (i=1; i<=4; i++) printf "%s%s",$i,OFS; for (; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s%s%s",$i,$(i+1),(i<NF?OFS:ORS) }' filename` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This may look very untidy but should work.

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=4; i++) {printf "%s  ",$i;} for(i=5; i<=NF; i++) {printf "%s", $i; if(i<NF){i++; printf "%s",$i;} printf "\t"} printf "\n"; }' filename
```

Here we print first 4 columns - with two space between them (so any original formatting between them is changed) - then print remaining columns by combining two to one and a tab between them (you can change tab to some number of spaces)